# Add Permissions to Installed App

Tags: permissions

I am having problems with 2 apps, QPython3 and SL4A.

I want to read my contacts from QPython3 and my user dictionary from SL4A.

The 2 apps do not have the relevant permissions.

Is there any way to add permissions to an installed app?

My phone is a rooted Nexus 5 running Kit-Kat.

Thank you

Comment: Even if you'd give the app those permissions, they'd have to implement the functionality you need

Comment: Why would you need to "add" permissions to an app? What purpose are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: They are both scripting apps. I want to write scripts that access those features. Thr functionality is already there

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add permissions to an installed app - they have to be declared in its Manifest before uploading to Google Play.